# Typegoose return PopulatedType from ref

Tags: mongoose, typegoose

I have a problem using Typegoose, I have defined a Ref on my schema like this:

```
export class LocationEntity {
    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public state: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public country: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public metro: string[];
}

export class FilterGroupEntity {
    public _id: ObjectId;

    @prop()
    public name: string;

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public jobs: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public sub_adcard_set: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public device_types: string[];

    @prop({ ref: () => LocationEntity })
    public location: Ref<LocationEntity>;
}
```

Then I have a method to find a filter group and then return only the location:

```
const parseFilterGroup = async (filterGroup: FilterGroupEntity): Promise<LocationEntity> => {
    return filterGroup.location;
}
```

But my issue is that filterGroup.location is type Ref<LocationEntity, ObjectId> and not just a LocationEntity.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If i understand this question correctly, you want to filter a array of `FilterGroupEntity`-documents based on if `location` is populated, then you should make use of [`isDocument`](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/functions/typeguards/is-document)

Comment: @hasezoey Actually my problem is that I want to return a document of LocationEntity and when I access the property location of a FilterGroupEntity this property is not a document, it is a Ref<LocationEntity, ObjectId> and I can not access the properties of this object. How can I access those properties?

Comment: Like i already said, you have to use the typeguard `isDocument` to check that it is a document, for example like `return isDocument(filterGroup.location) ? filterGroup.location : false` (or because it is just a filter which expects truthy/falsy values, it can just be `return isDocument(filterGroup.location)`), but if you need to more conditions you could also do `return isDocument(filterGroup.location) && filterGroup.location.lowerProperty`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue of handling the children as nested, for my use case it wasn't necessary to handle them as references. I preferred to change them to nested objects.

Here are the new schemas:

```js
export class LocationEntity {
    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public state: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public country: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public metro: string[];
}

export class FilterGroupEntity {
    public _id: ObjectId;

    @prop()
    public name: string;

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public jobs: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public sub_adcard_set: string[];

    @prop({ type: () => [String] })
    public device_types: string[];

    @prop()
    public location: LocationEntity;
}
```